# Creating my first command

Tags: formatting, color, italic

I want to create a command that will format code in a certain way. In this case I want code to be italic and red. So instead of doing `\textcolor{red}{\textit code}` I want to make a function, if you will, to do it for me with less lines of code. My understanding of it so far is very... basic. I just started using latex, this is what I have so far.

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{\textit #1}}
```

But this only prints out the first letter in italic. The colour seems fine though. Any help and explanations would be wonderously helpful.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you want: `\newcommand{\code}[1]{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{\textit{#1}}}`? Also, no need to load `color` *and* `xcolor`; it's enough to load `xcolor`.

Comment: Remember that `\textit` requires an argument: you want to say `\textcolor{red}{\textit{code}}` in your original method. And you need to say `\code{code}`, not `\code code`.

Comment: In addition to the above two comments I would suggest using creating the macro with two parameters and making the first one optional to specify the color (and default it to `ForestGreen`): `\newcommand{\code}[2][ForestGreen]{\textcolor{#1}{\textit{#2}}}`. The `\code{text}` will produce italics in `ForestGreen`, and `\code[red]{text}` will produce italics in red.

Comment: Thanks guys, that was an easy fix :). Also thanks for the tip to remove colors package, indeed it is not needed!

Comment: Also Greg you make a good point, I guess I didn't notice I forgot to add another set of curly braces.

Comment: @PeterGrill You should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Expanding on the comments of Gonzalo Medina and egreg, I would recommend create the macro `\code` as such:

```
    \newcommand{\code}[2][ForestGreen]{\textcolor{#1}{\textit{#2}}}
```

Then `\code{text}` and `\code[red]{text}` produce:

[image]

### Explanation:

- `[2]` so as to accept two parameters: `#1` and `#2`.
- To provide a default color, we make the first one (`#1`) optional via defining a default of `[ForestGreen]`.

### Notes:

- no need to load both `color` and `xcolor` packages -- just load `xcolor`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\code}[2][ForestGreen]{\textcolor{#1}{\textit{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\code{text} 

\code[red]{text} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, most has already been commented while I was composing an answer. I recommend that you have a look at the `xparse` package -- using it considerably simplyfies command definitions as soon as optional parameters and conditional branches are involved. You can find the [documentation on CTAN](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf), an example is included in the code given below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\format}[1]{%
    \textcolor{ForestGreen}{\textit{#1}}}

%format multiple paragraphs
\newcommand{\parformat}[1]{%
    {\color{ForestGreen} \itshape #1}}

%xparse version; [m]andatory text parameter,
%[O]ptional color parameter with a given default
\NewDocumentCommand{\xformat}{O{MidnightBlue} m}{%
    \textcolor{#1}{\textit{#2}}}    

%xparse version for long mandatory argument
\NewDocumentCommand{\xparformat}{O{MidnightBlue} +m}{%
    {\color{#1} \itshape #2}}   

\begin{document}

\noindent
\format{Formatted text}\\
\xformat{some more text}\\
\xformat[red]{yet more text}\\
\parformat{\lipsum[3]\par\lipsum[4]}
\xparformat[cyan]{\lipsum[3]\par\lipsum[4]}

\end{document}
```